# Can I close port 3306 if I dont use?

Tags: firewall, sql

I have a LAMP server. The port 3306 is opened.

I have a php program on the server, to make query and display it on the port 80.

Can I close it if I do not use SQL DB manager client software?

Comment: Hi, arryp,   I think, it is not necessary, to listen to on local host, if the server itself compromised from an another source, it is better to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to connect remotely to your DB from another host, you can just bind your mysql process to listen from only `localhost` `127.0.0.1`, or yes you can close that port from firewall.